# Spring Data pessimistic lock for creating a new Entity

Tags: java, transactions, spring-data, locking

We have more applications that write a record into the DB. The record can be identified by an unique recordName (which is not ID). They can both create the same record at the same time, but I want only one record to be created. The algorithm I want to use should look somehow like this:

```
start transaction, lock the table
check if the record with recordName is present in the table
if not present: create row
commit, release lock, end transaction
```

Is it possible to somehow use the pessimistic lock to ensure, that only one record will be created. I only found pessimistic locks to be used on Entities, not on whole tables.

Comment: Assign unique index to `recordName`. So that if a application tries to insert a record with same name then Db will throw error.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm running into the same problem. For now I'm relaying on the unique, just the same as @wak786 proposed. But it seems ugly as the second time, the record should be updated, not created. And instead of edit it after releasing the lock it throws the error due to the DB Constraint

Comment: @sebasira No, I didn't, it turned out, the the recordName is unfortunately not that unique. I think that JPA doesn't allow you to lock a table, however it enables you to lock an entity. I used a workaround which means I lock the entity that is responsible for putting a row into the table like this: `entityManager.lock(myEntity, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);`